# Using Sharepoint Online(Office 365) for a Public Facing SAS Application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

We are planning to Develop a Web Application(having user loads upto 5000) which will enable users to login using OpenID,register and pay for the service using Credit Cards , we are not sure if we can customize Sharepoint Online or use develop a custom asp.net web app

Are there examples of any sites which are using Sharepoint Online to host there SAS based service(like zendesk.com)?

Thanks